# rails_best_practices syntax of RemoveUnusedMethodsInControllersCheck for a namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to avoid the warning of rails_best_practices gem for a method that is used but the gem is not detecting it, maybe because there are some metaprogramming involved.

My problem is that the method is located in a namespaced controller and I don't know the syntax in the **rails_best_practices.yml**

I tried something like this:

```
RemoveUnusedMethodsInControllersCheck: { except_methods: [Namespace::Controller#method] }
```

but raises a syntax error: `'unexpected : '`, I also tried with a slash instead and it didn't raise any errors but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply the problem was yml syntax I solved surrounding it with quotas `'Namespace::Controller#method'`

Answer (score 2):

You have it correct but it must be a String. For instance, we are ignoring some Devise calls via this:

```
RemovedUnusedMethodsInControllersCheck: {
  except_methods: [
    'Users::RegistrationsController#passwords',
  ]
}
```